# Is there a way to get all this datas out and have them in an array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, function, object, methods

```
[{…}, {…}]
```

this is the data structure i have

when i open the object i have this
0: {name: "Radio", total: 11800}
1: {name: "Billboard", total: 350000}

Comment: Looks like they're already in an array to me.

Comment: i want to have name in a different array and total in a different array

Comment: i want to have name in a different array and total in a different array

Comment: Please show your exact original object, your exact desired result and your attempt at solving it as a [mcve]. See [ask]. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this

```js
let arr = [{name: "Radio", total: 11800}, {name: "Billboard", total: 350000}]

let names = arr.map(a=> a.name);
console.log(names);

let totals = arr.map(a=> a.total);
console.log(totals);
```